# I want to change the notification count on the notification icon if a condition is not met and set the count to 0 if the condition is not met

Tags: html, angularjs

notification List is defined in the root scope and is full but it should be set to 0 if the condition becomes false

```html
<button style="border-radius: 100%" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle"   type="button" data-ng-if="notification.createdBy==header_fullName" data-toggle="dropdown">{{notificationList.length}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
<button style="border-radius: 100%" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm dropdown-toggle"   type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{notification.createdBy==header_fullName ? notificationList.length : '0'}}</button>
```

Comment: HI, thanks for the answer the solution kind of worked, the notification count is still not showing 0, the icon disappears because of the ng-if tag